# Assembly: Append content to label

Tags: assembly, 68000, easy68k

I'm actually developing with asm one on Amiga (68k processor).

I'm stuck with this issue: how to append values to a label?
For example:

```
Copperlist:
    DC.w $11
    DC.w $ 12
    Rts
... ; Some code
 Bar:
    DC.w $13
```

Now I want to to append bar content to `Copperlist` in order to achieve `$11`,`$12`,`$13` on `Copperlist` label address...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have some program code between the `Copperlist` and `Bar` labels. If you want them contiguous in memory, then declare them next to each other, and have your code before or after the data. The `RTS` and other code in your example seem out of place and even unneeded.

e.g.

```
Start:
... your code

CopperList: DC.W $11, $12
Bar:        DC.W $13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two data areas adjacent to each other, you need to put them into your code like so.

1. Remove the `rts` at the end of `CopperList` - it seems unnecessary.
2. Move the `some code` between `CopperList` and `Bar` to somewhere else, it should run there just as well.

As `CopperList` doesn't seem to contain code, but rather data, I don't quite understand why you put a `rts` to the end - Your CPU should never run through this.